# How to define a threshold in Principal Component Image for Urban mapping?

Tags: remote-sensing, classification, satellite, digital-image-processing, land-cover

I am working on an Urban mapping and i would like to know how i could define a threshold value for extracting built-up areas from a PC (Principal Component) Image ?

I am interesting on how to determine a threshold value?

What are the most common methods of identifying thresholds in satellite Image Processing?

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems with thresholding is that there really is no good way to automate the optimization of a threshold value. There are several reasons for this.

When it comes to extracting features of interest, such as urban areas, there will be error no matter which threshold value you choose. If you select a value too high, classes start merging--to low and your features are not fully represented. Even values that are spot-on will have error due to the nature of a binary classification using a single data source such as PCA data.

Selecting a threshold value may be good for one snapshot in time, but when you try to automate threshold optimization across scenes temporally, there are many compounding factors that do not allow you to compare the images such as atmospheric effects, sun angle, time of day, season, etc.

In sum, thresholding is a handy technique for simple tasks, but has many limitations when you move toward more complicated tasks such as classifying urban areas. I would recommend a more sophisticated supervised classification algorithm such as maximum likelihood, random forests, SVM, etc... I would also advise using PCA as ancillary data combined with spectral data to improve the classification accuracy. Even better, look into an object oriented image analysis method such as image segmentation and classification.

Comment: ,My intention is not using PCA as a classification procedure but as an intermediate product. I am wanting to know the criteria for selecting thresholds from any floating point raster ( say -1 to 1), Should i use the mean of the raster values? Is there any recommended practice for selecting thresholds in floating point rasters?Like looking into the image's histogram and suggesting approximate one?

Comment: @Kaleab My advice holds true for thresholding any raster product, not just   PCA. You need to use your best judgement based on what features are important. There is no practical way to automate finding an optimal threshold value.